# Why does Visual Studio append the solution path to the root url when using default server?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cassini

When I use the default server in Visual Studio 2010 (Not sure if this is cassini or IIS?), the the last folder within the path at which I open the web site project (not a solution), is appended to the losthost url.

For example:

C:\myproject\mywebsite1\

Would open a url at the following:

http://localhost:x/mywebsite1/login.aspx.

This seems to cause problems with CSS files and javascript not resolving etc, but if I change the url to http://localhost:x/login.aspx I then get an error stating the aspx file is not present.

Why is an extra folder appended?  This is highly annoying, I just want the files being served to be in the root URL path as they are in the website project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your project, right click, properties and under the web tab, you should have checked Use Visual Studio Development Server, there you can specify a port and a virtual path, probably you have `/mywebsite1`  there, just delete that virtual path.

You asked this some time ago, but hope it helps anyway.

Comment: ok great thanks, I never got round to re-visiting this as I started using local IIS server rather than the built in one. I'll give it a go next time.